# Некорректное отображение данных в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет. Делаю задание по считыванию данных с файла (целых чисел) и выводу их в таблицу.

[image: Данные в файле]

Код считывания данных и попытки вывода в таблицу:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Header 1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Header 2");
            dt.Columns.Add("Header 3");

            var list = new List<List<int>>();
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");

            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var str = line.Split(' ');
                var numbers = new List<int>();
                foreach (var item in str)
                {
                    numbers.Add(int.Parse(item));
                }
                list.Add(numbers);
            }

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(item);
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Результат выполнения:

[image: Скриншот таблицы]

Не могу понять в чём проблема. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании колонок в DataTable вы не указываете явно их тип: `dt.Columns.Add("Header 1");`. По умолчанию им будет назначен тип `string`. Поэтому ваши дальнейшие действия по конвертации значений в `int` не имеют смысла, т. к. при вставке в DataTable они будут снова преобразованы в `string`.

Если вам нужны именно числа, то явно укажите тип:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Header 1", typeof(int));
```

Дальнейший код в любом случае можно упростить до следующего:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var str = line.Split(' ');
    dt.Rows.Add(str);
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Преобразование в `int` (если указан именно этот тип) будет выполнено автоматически.